# Running main.cpp file in terminal with ncurse header

Tags: c++, xcode, terminal, ncurses

I am using the ncurse.h header file to make a snake game, however since you can't simply run a game in xcode, I've tried opening it up and running it in the terminal but the terminal spits out a lot of errors. I've tried reading through this to see if theres any information I can get out of it to resolve in my actual program, but there is nothing of relevance in there that I can find. I tried adding the -lncurses to the compiler flag in the build phases section of my xcode program but that doesn't do anything as far as I can tell.

**UPDATE**: I've now tried using `g++ main.cpp -o pocs -lncurses` which has resolved all of my errors, however when I execute the program and then access it in terminal and paste the command, nothing happens. Perhaps its something wrong with my syntax in the program itself?

Comment: You should compile with `g++`, not `gcc`.

Comment: @StoryTeller ok I tried doing g++ main.cpp -lncurses -o pocs main.cpp instead and I'm getting new errors now such as:


    /var/folders/pf/4ms_3z0d3hd1z75ytsqccfph0000gn/T/main-9d59b6.o
    /var/folders/pf/4ms_3z0d3hd1z75ytsqccfph0000gn/T/main-422272.o
duplicate symbol '_x' in:
    /var/folders/pf/4ms_3z0d3hd1z75ytsqccfph0000gn/T/main-9d59b6.o
    /var/folders/pf/4ms_3z0d3hd1z75ytsqccfph0000gn/T/main-422272.o
duplicate symbol 'draw()' in:
    /var/folders/pf/4ms_3z0d3hd1z75ytsqccfph0000gn/T/main-9d59b6.o
    /var/folders/pf/4ms_3z0d3hd1z75ytsqccfph0000gn/T/main-422272.o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are specifying `main.cpp` twice:

```
g++ main.cpp -lncurses -o pocs main.cpp
    ^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^
```

Hence the dupes.  Drop the second from the command line:

```
g++ main.cpp -o pocs -lncurses
```

Comment: I no longer get the errors, but when I paste that command in once I access the folder, nothing happens.

Comment: Thank you! Fixed the solution. I needed to change the pocs in the code line to play.